# How to make Maven run test cases alone skipping previous lifecycle phases?

Tags: maven-2

I have my test classes already copmpiled as part of nightly build.
I just want to execute Junits.How can I go ahead with this by skipping previous lifeccycles phases?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute a Maven goal directly without going through all the lifecycle phases.

In your case, you can simply run `mvn surefire:test` or `mvn failsafe:integration-test` directly to achieve what you want.

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html) for more.